# Natural Deduction Fitch Proof - Double Negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having issues with the proof of the double negation rule.
[To prove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxmPr.png)

The proof must be done without using : ¬I, ¬¬E, RAA, ¬¬I

Useful rules to complete :
[Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSOb2.png)

This is what I have so far:

1- ¬¬ϕ (premise)

2- ¬¬ϕ ∨ ¬ϕ (LEM)

3- ¬ϕ (assum. 1)

4- ⊥  (¬E)

5- ϕ  (0E)

6- ¬¬ϕ (assum. 2)

... stuck here

Comment: The question looks way better with images in it. I simply can't have them being directly showing because reputation points < 10

Comment: The linked "Useful rules to complete" are not sufficient to prove $\neg\neg$E, because those rules are all valid in intuitionistic logic whereas $\neg\neg$E isn't.  Do you have some other rules (or axioms) available? For instance $A\lor\neg A$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Hey thank you for helping me out!, We have access to all natural deduction rule expect the one listed up there. I only have 1 axiom (¬¬E).